# Data appending to a file and when its value has crossed 200 MB new file should be created

Tags: linux, logs

I have written a script that runs `ps -ef` every 5 minutes and the output gets appended to a file. I want to get a new file created when the present file size exceeds 200MB. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: are you open to using a general-purpose tool like `logrotate` for this, or do you have to do it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You could add something like this to your script, before you are appending the file.

```
FILE="your-file"
if test $(( $(stat  -c"%s" "$FILE") )) -ge "$(( 200*1024*1024 ))"; then
    mv "$FILE" "$FILE-$(date +"%FT%T")"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `logrotate` program.
First, create a configuration file, say, `/home/john/logrotate/ps.conf`, with content like this: (assuming you dump your `ps` output to `/home/john/logrotate/log/ps.log`)

```
/home/john/logrotate/log/ps.log {
    size = 200MB
    missingok
    notifempty
}
```

Then you can create a crontab to run `/usr/bin/logrotate /home/john/logrotate/ps.conf`.  See [man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) for more options, such as compression.